# What paper or papers about molecules did Heisenberg "like", and what has Heisenberg published or otherwise commented about it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg

In the 2023 film [Oppenheimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppenheimer_(film)) based on the 2005 biography [American Prometheus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Prometheus) by Kai Bird and Martin J. Sherwin, there seems to be two references to work by Oppenheimer on molecules:

> RABI: I caught your lecture on molecules. Caught some of it.

and

> HEISENBERG: I liked your paper on molecules.

I'm guessing this reference is related in some way to what we now call the [Born–Oppenheimer approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation) since (earlier?) Bohr had sent him to Göttingen to study with Born.

**Question:** What paper or papers about molecules did Heisenberg "like", and what has Heisenberg published or otherwise commented about it in a well-documented way?

Comment: Hmmmm… nothing on Facebook from Heisenberg about molecules…

Comment: Is that Heisenberg quote also in the book?

Comment: When did Heisenberg like it?  The Wikipedia page you linked links to the Born-Oppenheimer 1927 paper, [*Zur Quantentheorie der Molekeln*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/andp.19273892002) and cites Heisenberg-Oppenheimer 1924 paper on the same subject done under the old quantum mechanics. The work in the1927 paper was mostly done by Oppenheimer himself, Born was his advisor. See [Paris, Oppenheimer’s science beyond the Manhattan Project](https://pubs.aip.org/physicstoday/online/42547) for a general review of Oppenheimer’s work.

Comment: @Conifold sadly I have not read the book yet, so let this be the impetus - the neutron that triggers the release of enough energy to kick my butt to the library and get a copy today :-)